# Vuetify - v-data-table: row separator lines and mouseover

Tags: vuetify.js

Im creating a table in vue/vuetify, the `<v-data-table>` component.
I can't seem to figure out how to draw the table without the row separator lines, nor can I disable row highlighting when the mouse hovers.

Answer (score 0):

Give your table an id (say `mytable`), then add the following css (the first removes the lines, the second the hover effect)

```
#mytable tr:not(:last-child)>td {
  border-bottom: unset;
}
#mytable tr:hover {
  background-color: unset;
}
```